# iPhone with iOS7 does not allow tap to select an option of an HTML select element

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, jquery-mobile, mobile

With a responsive site, I am trying to include functionality to allow users to tap to select an option of an html select element when viewed on iOS7 iPhone's native browser (safari). By default the native select menu will only make a selection when the user hits the "X" in the upper right hand corner of the select wheel popup menu. Our concern is that we would like to reduce the amount of steps for the user. Alternatively the user will tap the drop down menu on the page, then tap the option of the select element they want in the native menu. No need to confirm with the "Done" or "X" on the right hand side. Thanks for any incite.

Comment: Overriding how iOS renders `<select>` isn't an option, I'm afraid. If you don't like it, you shouldn't use one. Use a list of text links or radio buttons instead.